# Convert JS coding to xml

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am working with sapui5 and I am new, I have a js view, but I need to convert it to XML view, is there any way to convert it?

Thanks

Comment: there are different posts on this, long story short: no it is not possible to convert it in an easy way.. start creating in XML.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of SAPUI5 Diagnostics tool to convert js View to XML.

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/6e/c18e80b0ce47f290bc2645b0cc86e6/content.htm

Comment: What if your link is dead in a few weeks/months/years? No one will be able to see the answer. That's why you should include the answer in your post. The link is only seen as a source for your actual answer. (PS, I didn't downvote you).

Comment: Thanks. But the solution for the question is simple. Just have to use the tool mentioned in the answer. The OP was just too lazy to search.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you create your views either as Javascript-, HTML- or XML-View. If you want to know how to represent a particular control in XML instead of Javascript this link is a good entry point: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html

Answer (score -1):

try this: 
1- in your UI5 app (browser Chrome): "Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S"
2- select the view you want to convert
3- in the right side of the window select Export and then Export to xml (see image below)

[UI5 Diagnostics for exporting views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7gE5.jpg)

I hope it helps,
Gabriel